# Поведение this. Почему, ведь this ссылается на windows

Tags: javascript, this

```
function f(){
   alert(this)
}
f.call(f)
```

Результат в окне - function f(){alert(this)}. Почему?

Comment: в js `this` -- это объект, у которого была вызывана функция. Извенить `this` можно путем связывания. Если же функция вызывается без объекта, то `this` -- это, вроде бы, сама функция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала надо понять что делает функция. Она выдает значение this.
 this в функции - window (не windows).

```js
function f(){
   alert(this)
}
f() // в этом случае выдаст оригинальное значение this
```

Но  если вы привязываете контекст, использую call, то this'ом становиться то, что вы указали. Вы указали функцию определенную. Вот функция и вызывает alert c кодом этой функции.

```js
function f(){
   alert(this)
}
f.call(f)
```

Легко понять на примере:

```js
function f(){
   alert(this)
}
f.call('1');
```