# Откуда в сall попадает this

Tags: javascript

Есть функция декоратор, в которой вызывается метод объекта. Я писал в декораторе `let result = func(x);` и тем самым терял контекст. Нашел решение, что надо писать так `let result = func.call(this, x);`, но никак не могу понять как в call попадает this=worker. Я думал, что в функции cachingDecorator this  ссылается на window.

```js
let worker = {
    someMethod() {
      return 1;
    },
  
    slow(x) {
      console.log("Called with " + x);
      return x * this.someMethod(); // (*)
    }
};

function cachingDecorator(func) {
    return function(x) {   
        // let result = func(x); потеря контекста
        let result = func.call(this, x); //почему this=worker, хотя обычно в функциях this=window
        return result;
    };
}
  
console.log( worker.slow(1) ); 
worker.slow = cachingDecorator(worker.slow); 
console.log( worker.slow(2) )
```

Comment: this'ом становится тот объект, который стоит слева от точки. Когда вы вызываете `worker.slow(2)`, у вас слева от точки стоит `worker`, поэтому именно он и становится this'ом внутри функции

Comment: Если вы избавитесь от точки и попробуете вызвать `worker['slow'](2)`, то this'ом опять станет Window

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поведение this. Почему, ведь this ссылается на windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068580/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-this-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-this-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows)

Comment: @4500zenja не дубликат, потому что тут вопрос не про принципы работы функции call

Answer (score 1):

```
worker.slow(2)
```

здесь `slow` это анонимная функция `function(x) {...}`, вызванная в контексте `worker`.